# SSRS Visual Studio 2008 Format Multiple Textboxes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, formatting, report-designer

I'm creating large reports in Visual Studio 2008 SSRS and am getting frustrated with converting the information in individual text boxes. Say, the values are returned as decimals (x.xx) but I want to truncate them to just an integer (x) I have to right click the cell, text box properties, number, decimal, close for every one of them.

I want to either find a shortcut via a formatting button that might exist that I can't find, or, format multiple cells at a time, or write a custom code that converts the values returned (say, Fields!Weight.Value) to an integer.

Solution:
I found an easy solution using custom code

```
Public Function TruncateNumber(ByVal Value As Integer) as String
    dim i = Cint(Value)
    return i
End Function
```

then reference it in the text box's expression

```
=Code.TruncateNumber(Fields!yourdecimal.Value)
```

hope this helps someone out there

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do the same thing. I'm sure you tried all if these, but they're good to have in the tool belt.

1) Do a find and replace in the XMl code of the RDL. Of course this can cause errors, but sometimes it's the last resort.

2) Sometimes you can select a range of cells and change a parameter that applies to all of them. Sometimes a few cells don't match, thus blocking this method. For instance you want to change formatting to A, the majority of the cells are in B, and a few have formatting C. Change all the Cs to Bs, then you can do a group chance to A.

3) Assuming you are doing this from scratch and not updating an existing report, format the cell how you want and copy and paste, thus replicating the formatting.

Your solution will help me in the future, thanks. Don't you have to add this to all the text boxes?

Comment: you do-but its pretty easy to just add the function since you're going to edit the expression anyway - this was just a time saver from having to right click, text box properties, numbers, numbering type, decimal points. I'm sure there's better optimization - what I'd love to do is be able to add something to the toolbar that applies this effect.

Comment: Ah, I normally go to Format in the Properties window (View _ Properties Window) and put in D, for numeric. You can select many cells and format as D that way.  But it sounds like you're application needs it done differently. Format codes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx